# T SQL multi thread for launching xp_cmdshell jobs

Tags: sql, multithreading, xp-cmdshell

I have a job that takes database backup files and compresses them to .7z files using seven zips command line utility and at the moment it takes about 8 hours to run through all the .bak files because it is doing one at a time. This is running on has about 16 cores and the 7z process only seems to be using 1 core so I would like to be able to run multiply instances of the xp_cmdshell command to have it compress several files at a time. Is there any way to execute a list of commands in T SQL on MSSQL Server 2005?

I have post my script below.

This is a link to the program I am using to zip the files.
[http://downloads.sourceforge.net/sevenzip/7za920.zip][1]

```
-- YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
-- II       zip all files in a folder                       II
-- VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV

-- Zip and then Delete all files from the backup folder
-- List all files in a directory - T-SQL parse string for date and filename 
DECLARE  @PathName       VARCHAR(256) , 
         @CMD            VARCHAR(512) 

CREATE TABLE #CommandShell ( Line VARCHAR(512)) 

    -- To use the xp_cmdshell option it has to be enabled. you can use the script bellow to enable it.
    --
    -- -- run exec sp_configure to see if the option exists in this list and you can check if it is enabled.
    -- EXEC sp_configure
    -- go
    -- -- if you don't see xp_cmdshell in the list then you will have to enable advanced options first 
    -- -- before you can enable the xp_cmdshell option.
    -- EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
    -- go
    -- reconfigure
    -- go
    -- -- if xp_cmdshell is in the list then you should just need to run this script.
    -- exec sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1
    -- go
    -- reconfigure

SET @PathName = 'D:\FILES\Backups\' 

SET @CMD = 'DIR ' + @PathName + ' /TC' 

INSERT INTO #CommandShell 
EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell   @CMD 

-- Delete lines not containing filename
DELETE 
FROM   #CommandShell 
WHERE  Line NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %' 
OR Line LIKE '%<DIR>%'
OR Line is null

-- SQL reverse string function - charindex string function 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY REVERSE( LEFT(REVERSE(Line),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(line))-1 ) )) AS ROW_NUM,
  FileName = REVERSE( LEFT(REVERSE(Line),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(line))-1 ) ),
  CreateDate = LEFT(Line,10)
INTO #tempFileList 
FROM #CommandShell
WHERE REVERSE( LEFT(REVERSE(Line),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(line))-1 ) ) LIKE '%.bak'
ORDER BY FileName

DROP TABLE #CommandShell

DECLARE @FileMaxRownum INT
SET @FileMaxRownum = (SELECT MAX(ROW_NUM) FROM #tempFileList)

DECLARE @FileIter INT
SET @FileIter = (SELECT MIN(ROW_NUM) FROM #tempFileList)

WHILE @FileIter <= @FileMaxRownum
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DelFile varchar(200)
    --@@
    DECLARE @cmd2 VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @cmd2 = null
    DECLARE @db_bkp_files_dir varchar(100)
    SET @db_bkp_files_dir = null
    DECLARE @archive_destination_dir varchar(100)
    SET @archive_destination_dir = null
    DECLARE @archive_name varchar(100)
    SET @archive_name = null
    DECLARE @7z_path varchar(100)
    SET @7z_path = null
    set @archive_destination_dir = @PathName --destination dir
    set @7z_path = 'D:\FILES'
    set @db_bkp_files_dir = right(@PathName,1) --db backup files origin 
    SELECT TOP(1) @archive_name = FileName FROM #tempFileList WHERE ROW_NUM = @FileIter
    SET @cmd2 = @7z_path + '\7za a -t7z -mx5 -ms=off ' + @archive_destination_dir + @archive_name + '.7z ' +  @archive_destination_dir + @archive_name
    print @cmd2
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd2
    --@@
    SELECT TOP(1) @DelFile = 'del ' + @PathName + FileName FROM #tempFileList WHERE ROW_NUM = @FileIter
    EXEC xp_cmdshell @DelFile
    SET @FileIter = @FileIter + 1
END
DROP TABLE #tempFileList
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the issue is with SQL Server. If you wanted to run multiple threads of execution at the same time, you would do so with scheduled jobs in SQL Server agent... but, this is just a workaround for the compression algorithm in 7-Zip that you're using.

[The default compression won't use more than two cores, but an alternate compression algorithm, such as b-zip, will make better use of your server's available cores.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/02/file-compression-in-the-multi-core-era.html)

Instead of using the `-t7z` switch, try using `-tbzip2`, which is the algorithm detailed in the blog post above.

```
SET @cmd2 = @7z_path + '\7za a -tbzip2 -mx5 -ms=off ' 
  + @archive_destination_dir 
  + @archive_name + '.7z ' 
  + @archive_destination_dir 
  + @archive_name
```

Comment: I tested the -tbzip option (had to remove the "-ms=off" option to get it to work), and it does the compression a lot faster but is a bigger file at the end so I ended up using -t7z option and going with your other suggesting and creating Server agent jobs for each file because I have about 30 different databases so this option still gave me a fairly good speed up and used all the cores on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is the script I ended up using to test speeding up the process. It leaves the jobs in the msdb database when it finishes so I have to go back and delete all the jobs that have been added after they finish running, so it is a bit messy and if I hadn't already setup permissions for the server agent service and the folder I am accessing I think it would have giving me errors there. 
I will probably rewrite this and just create separate backup and compress jobs for each database so I am not dropping and creating server agent jobs all the time but this worked for testing.

```
-- YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
-- II       zip all files in a folder                       II
-- VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV

-- Zip and then Delete all files from the backup folder
-- List all files in a directory - T-SQL parse string for date and filename 
DECLARE  @PathName       VARCHAR(256) , 
         @CMD            VARCHAR(512) 

CREATE TABLE #CommandShell ( Line VARCHAR(512)) 

SET @PathName = 'D:\FILES\Backups\' 

SET @CMD = 'DIR ' + @PathName + ' /TC' 

INSERT INTO #CommandShell 
EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell   @CMD 

-- Delete lines not containing filename
DELETE 
FROM   #CommandShell 
WHERE  Line NOT LIKE '[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9]/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9] %' 
OR Line LIKE '%<DIR>%'
OR Line is null

-- SQL reverse string function - charindex string function 
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY REVERSE( LEFT(REVERSE(Line),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(line))-1 ) )) AS ROW_NUM,
  FileName = REVERSE( LEFT(REVERSE(Line),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(line))-1 ) ),
  CreateDate = LEFT(Line,10)
INTO #tempFileList 
FROM #CommandShell
WHERE REVERSE( LEFT(REVERSE(Line),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(line))-1 ) ) LIKE '%.bak'
ORDER BY FileName

DROP TABLE #CommandShell

DECLARE @FileMaxRownum INT
SET @FileMaxRownum = (SELECT MAX(ROW_NUM) FROM #tempFileList)

DECLARE @FileIter INT
SET @FileIter = (SELECT MIN(ROW_NUM) FROM #tempFileList)

WHILE @FileIter <= @FileMaxRownum
BEGIN
    DECLARE @DelFile varchar(200)
    --@@
    DECLARE @cmd2 VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @cmd2 = null
    DECLARE @db_bkp_files_dir varchar(100)
    SET @db_bkp_files_dir = null
    DECLARE @archive_destination_dir varchar(100)
    SET @archive_destination_dir = null
    DECLARE @archive_name varchar(100)
    SET @archive_name = null
    DECLARE @7z_path varchar(100)
    SET @7z_path = null
    set @archive_destination_dir = @PathName --destination dir
    set @7z_path = 'D:\FILES'
    set @db_bkp_files_dir = right(@PathName,1) --db backup files origin 
    SELECT TOP(1) @archive_name = FileName FROM #tempFileList WHERE ROW_NUM = @FileIter
    --   7za switches: 
    --   -mx0 (Don't compress)
    --   -mx1 (Low)
    --   -mx3 (Fast)
    --   -mx5 (Normal)
    --   -mx7 (Maximum)
    --   -mx9 (Ultra)
    --
    --   -mmt (enable multithreading)
    --   
    --   -t7z
    --   -tbzip2
    SET @cmd2 = @7z_path + '\7za a -t7z -mx5 -ms=off ' + @archive_destination_dir + @archive_name + '.7z ' +  @archive_destination_dir + @archive_name
    --SET @cmd2 = @7z_path + '\7za a -tbzip2 -mx5 ' + @archive_destination_dir + @archive_name + '.7z ' +  @archive_destination_dir + @archive_name

    DECLARE @cmd3 nvarchar(max)
    SET @cmd3 = 'USE msdb; EXEC sp_add_job @job_name = N''' + @archive_name + ' Zip job' + ''''

    DECLARE @cmd4 nvarchar(max)
    SET @cmd4 = 'USE msdb; EXEC sp_add_jobstep @job_name = N''' + @archive_name + ' Zip job' +''', @step_name = N''' + @archive_name + ' Zip job Step 1'  + ''', ' +
                '@subsystem = N''TSQL'', @command = N''' + 'DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(1000) SET @cmd = ''''' + @7z_path + '\7za a -t7z -mx5 -ms=off ' + @archive_destination_dir + @archive_name + '.7z ' +  @archive_destination_dir + @archive_name + ''''' EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd '  + ''', @retry_attempts = 5, @retry_interval = 1'

    DECLARE @cmd5 nvarchar(max)
    SET @cmd5 = 'USE msdb; EXEC dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_name = N''' + @archive_name + ' Zip job' + ''', @server_name = N''ServerName'';'

    DECLARE @cmd6 nvarchar(max)
    SET @cmd6 = 'USE msdb; EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N''' + @archive_name + ' Zip job' + ''';'

    DECLARE @cmd7 nvarchar(max)
    SET @cmd7 = 'EXEC sp_delete_job @job_name = N''' + @archive_name + ' Zip job' + ''';'

    PRINT @cmd3
    EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @cmd3
    PRINT @cmd4
    EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @cmd4
    PRINT @cmd5
    EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @cmd5
    PRINT @cmd6
    EXEC sp_executesql @statement = @cmd6

    PRINT @cmd7

    --print @cmd2
    --EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd2
    --@@
    SELECT TOP(1) @DelFile = 'del ' + @PathName + FileName FROM #tempFileList WHERE ROW_NUM = @FileIter
    --EXEC xp_cmdshell @DelFile
    SET @FileIter = @FileIter + 1
END
DROP TABLE #tempFileList
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a @delete_level parameter for sp_add_job, and it allows to have the job deleted automatically upon successful completion.

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259577(v=sql.80).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259577%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers